# how to change rails datetime_field defaults?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, date, localdate

Me and my co-workers were testing my web app. And, in the form in my computer/local/dev and server/production it shows the date format `dd/mm/yyyy 00:00` and for my coworkers `mm/dd/yyyy 00:00 am/pm` with the same local chrome settings and computer settings.

- why is this?
- and how can I change this for all users? if possible.

piece of code:

```
<div class="mini_jumbotron">
                <div class="mini_text">Inicio<%= image_tag("calendar.png", :class => "calendar")%>
                  </div> <br>
                </div>
              <%= f.datetime_field :Inicio %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<%= f.date_field :Inicio, as: :date, value: f.object.try(:strftime,"%d/%m/%Y"), class: 'form-control' %>
```

You can also use this gem: https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails
on your gemfile.rb

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

**then bundle install and restart rails server**

then add this line to **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
*= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

and add this line to **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

and to use this in your form:

```
<%= f.date_field :Inicio, :id => "datepicker" %>
```

**and add this javascript on the same view of your form**

```
<script>
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy  HH:MM:ss'});
</script>
```

Comment: it worked, but how do I add hours and minutes to it?

Comment: replace `$('#datepicker').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});` with `$('#datepicker').datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy H:M'});`

Comment: try `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss'`

Comment: still only shows dd/mm/yyyy, it doesnt show the hour minute or seconds

Comment: Try to change date_field to datetime_field